# Delete the foreign key from MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, key, primary-key

I have a problem when I'm trying to DROP a column that is a foreign key for other table. Column was created by mistake.

```
First table 'users' with Columns 'ID (Primary key)','user_rest_id(Foreign key)'
Second table 'rest' with Columns 'ID (Primary key)','user_id(Foreign key)'
```

I'm trying to drop 'user_rest_id' column. I created it by a mistake and it is connected with table 'rest' 'ID'.

On column drop:

> #1553 - Cannot drop index 'user_rest_id': needed in a foreign key constraint.

When I try to drop foreign key it says:

> #1091 - Can't DROP 'user_rest_id'; check that column/key exists

Comment: You may need to determine the constraint name that corresponds to the foreign key on `user_rest_id` and drop the FK constraint using that name, and only then can you drop the columns.  Since your outline schema doesn't document which columns in which tables are referenced by the FKs, I'm not completely sure how much of a mess you've got.  It might be that you have an FK from Users to Rest and another from Rest to Users.

Comment: Exactly as you said. I have created it by a mistake. 'user_rest_id' should be just simple column, not a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming That you have created foreign key using constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE users
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_users; //Your actual constraint name
```

Hope This Helps.